# Trouble with tsql not in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find rows where a value in table 1 column A are not in table 2 column A

This is the query...

```
SELECT contactsid
FROM contacts
WHERE (email1 NOT IN (SELECT email
                      FROM old_contact))
```

It returns 0 rows, which I know is incorrect. There are many rows in `contacts.email1` that are not in `old_contact.email`

How should I be writing this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT contactsid
FROM Contacts a
LEFT JOIN old_contact b
ON a.email1 = b.email
WHERE b.email IS NULL
```

This will join `Contacts` to `old_contact` using a `LEFT JOIN` -- a type of join that, based on the join condition, returns all records from the left side (i.e. `Contacts`) even if no records exist on the right side.  Then, the `WHERE` clause filters the results so that it returns *only* the records from the left side where the ride side records don't exist.

Answer (score 7):

My guess is that `old_contract.email` takes on a `NULL` value.

For this reason, `not exists` is often a better choice:

```
SELECT contactsid
FROM contacts c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM old_contract oc
                  WHERE c.email = oc.email1
                 ) ;
```

You could also add `where email1 is not null` to the subquery.  However, I find just using `not exists` is generally safer in case I forget that condition.